# find values in map of map & return primary map's keys (or alternative)

Tags: c++, dictionary, websocket, find, key-value

I'm writing a websocket++ server for a site that's mostly a few pages with article listings like you'd see on any social news site or the questions link on stack; however, I dynamically change the shown articles via faux buttons and sliders as well as update them with websocket pushes.

I need to store, of course, each connection, but I also want the site to remember where each user is on each page.  This is an index position of the articles for each page.

If I use (psuedocode): `map<sessionid, map<page, index>>`, can I find the `index` directly?  If not, what code should I use to achieve this?

If you can, please balance between minimal lines of code & max performance.

**multiple `sessionid`s**

Sorry, forgot that many people will probably be looking at the same `index` per `page`, so it needs to output a `set` (unless if there's something better) of only `sessionid`s.

So, in pseudocode, it might look like `findPageIndex(map<sessionid, map<page, index>>, page, index)` and return `set<sessionid>`.

**`page`s**

Every time a session is created, the `index`es will default to `0` for each `page` until a user changes them.

**reasoning**

The purpose of this format is to update the user whenever another user changes an article through votes, comments, etc.  I want that new data immediately sent back to the the client looking at those articles.

So:

1. User1 updates article1 in the database
2. server finds all users looking at article1
3. server updates all users looking at article1

This is my best guess at how stack and other advanced sites do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: Why not just use two maps.  One for `map<sessionid, page>` and then another for `map<sessionid, index`>  Or keep both page/index into a "Location" struct so that you can say `map<sessonid, location>` ?

Comment: @selbie because I want to store multiple pages' information simultaneously.  I'm using jQuery to do a spa, so I need all pages' information stored at all times for rapidity as they flip through the pages.

Comment: @AndyProwl probably superfluous, but i know the key can be found but not the value

Comment: So you want to return all the `sessionId`s for which there is a pair `(page, index)` in the map associated to that `sessionId`?

Comment: @AndyProwl bingo!  if I pass 'page' and 'index', i need all `sessionid`s that have the same `index` for the `page` that i pass.  The `page` `index`es will always default to `0` and be stored when the session is created, so there's no need to see if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and provided you are given a `sessionId` and a `page`, you could just do a nested search (here I am assuming `sessionId`, `page`, and `index` are all type aliases for `int`, but that doesn't have to be the case obviously).

This is how you could do it in C++11:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

int find_index(
    std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> const& m,
    int sessionId,
    int pageId)
{
    auto i = m.find(sessionId);
    if (i != m.end())
    {
        auto j = i->second.find(pageId);
        if (j != i->second.end())
        {
            return j->first;
        }
    }

    throw std::logic_error("Invalid coordinates");
}
```

This is how you could use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> m;
    m[42] = std::map<int, int>{{1729, 6}};

    std::cout << find_index(m, 42, 1729);
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24132).

---

**UPDATE:**

After the edit, it turned out the requirements where quite different. If I understood correctly, given a `page` and an `index`, you want to retrieve all the `sessionId`s for which there is apage -> index` association in the corresponding inner map. In that case, the algorithm could look like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> find_sessions_by_page_and_index(
    std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> const& m,
    int page,
    int index)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (auto const& p : m)
    {
        auto i = p.second.find(page);
        if ((i != p.second.end()) && (i->second == index))
        {
            result.push_back(p.first);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> m;
    m[42] = std::map<int, int>{{1729, 6}};
    m[24] = std::map<int, int>{{1729, 6}};
    m[5] = std::map<int, int>{{1729, 12}};
    m[10] = std::map<int, int>{{9271, 6}};

    auto v = find_sessions_by_page_and_index(m, 1729, 6);
    for (auto x : v)
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

And of course the [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24143).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!  Can I be greedy and ask you to modify per my edit?  Sorry, I just realized that all I'll need is the `sessionid`.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: Sorry, I didn't see a notification for your message somehow. Will check your edit and update the answer

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your format is exactly what I'm looking for.  Sorry for not having the question better organized from the start. :/

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: I'm not sure I have it clear: I understand you want to return a set of `sessionID`s, but what is your input? The `index`? Or the `page` + the `index`?

Comment: Sry, I mangled your code with pseudo.  I want to pass the multidimensional `map` as in your example, the `page` that I'm interested in because a user will only be viewing one, and the `index` to see if the user's looking at the article that was just updated (votes, comments, etc).  There will be multiple `page`s because I want that info always at hand when a user flips through them. I need to get a `set` (or something you think's better) of any `sessionid` that has an `index` of a specified `page` because more than one user could be viewing the specified `index of the specified `page`. ty!!!!!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: I updated the answer. Could you check if it does what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with me and this awesome code!

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef map<page, index> page_map;
typedef map<sessionid, page_map> ses_map;

ses_map the_map; // The main map
index index_wanted;  // The index you are looking for.

for(ses_map::iterator ses_it = the_map.begin(); ses_it != the_map.end(); ++ses_it) {
    for(page_map::iterator page_iter = ses_it->second.begin(); page_iter != ses_it->second.end(); ++page_iter) {
        if(index_wanted == page_iter->second) {
            // Found it!
        }
    }
}
```